# How to only print lines that are different from the previous line in a live feed in bash?

Tags: bash, text-processing

Say for example, that I have a script that looks like this:

```
while true
do
echo $randomvar
done
```

where the output might look like this:

```
foo
foo
foo
bar
bar
foo
```

What could I add after the echo to make the output look like this?:

```
foo
bar
foo
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `uniq` command:

```
while true
do
echo $randomvar
done | uniq
```